# Good refresher course on 'O(N)' type stuff?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, big-o

Learned all about computing algorithm costs in College, but that was so long ago I forgot it all.  Is there any sort of walkthrough that goes over the whole subject matter? I feel as though there was more than I currently remember. I want to refresh some of my core skills.

Comment: if you close, provide a reason why! if you close it as duplicate, post the link. otherwise don't botter closing questions!

Comment: I usually am against closing questions, but felt OK closing this one since it was my own (anf my first close!) but the first answer has a link to a good substitute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Big-O for Eight Year Olds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107165/big-o-for-eight-year-olds)

Comment: Brilliant.  Too bad the search function isnt better here, I might have come across that one

Comment: I found this with a site search for 'O notation'

Comment: Ya but at the time I forgot it was called "o notation"

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to  find various tutorials by searching for complexity analysis.

[Wikipedia (Analysis of algorithms)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) is always a good place to get a quick refresher.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good resource with some tests:

[Complexity and Big-O Notation](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs367-3/readings/Complexity/)