# Big O and Tree Traversal

Tags: c++, tree, big-o, traversal

If I had a function like this:

```
void myfunction(node* root)
{
   for(int i = 0; i<root->children.size();i++)
   {
      myfunction(root->children[i]);
   }
}
```

Would that be Big O of n^2 or Big O of n?  If you have a for loop and inside that for loop a function call to itself, is the Big O the number of iterations times the function?

Comment: Yes, I would love to do your homework for you.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: There are lot of similar threads in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107165/big-o-for-eight-year-olds, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o, etc.

Comment: It is O(n^98345984375743598734598734953752345).

Answer (score 9):

This is an in-order traversal of an n-tree, but you hit every element, so it's O(n) (big-theta is more appropriate).

Comment: New user asking a very academic question = probably homework.  I hope you at least understand the fundamentals of why this is O(n).

Comment: The O(n) is correct, but it's not an in-order traversal. One could argue that it's pre-order or post-order, but there's no way to *really* tell since the function does no work at each node, it just visits them. Doing something before the for loop would be pre-order — doing something after the for loop would be post-order.

Comment: Let's just call it a depth-first traversal.  We know that much, at least :)

Comment: Ah yes, he doesn't actually do any node processing so it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 2):

It is a recursive function call. You shall need a bit of looking into **recurrence relations** to calculate the time complexity in Big O notation.  Your reasoning is correct in a *general* case. In this specific case, the answers have already been posted.

EDIT: Refer this [link](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html) for a discussion of Big-Oh for Recursive Functions.

Comment: +1: In a recursive operation, esp. for a beginner, have to stop and consider what n really is.  In this case, not depth, or breadth, but simply total number of tree nodes.

Comment: Recurrences are definitely a key tool for the analysis of recursive functions, but in this particular case it looks like he *might* have a variable number of children at each node. Constructing and solving a recurrence in that case would be pretty hairy. For this problem it's best to just think about how the function is visiting nodes as others have described.

Answer (score 2):

You can work this out by considering what happens to a tree with N nodes.

The function will be called once for every node in the tree so is both O(N) and Big-Theta(N).

Consider how it doesn't matter how wide the tree is verses how tall the tree is for the big O value, it still has the same number of visits to make.

That said the depth versus width *does* affect the *space* considerations of the function.

If the tree is extremely wide (say the width is such that the depth is always constant for any N) then the stack space required for the traversal is constant.
If however the width was a fixed constant value > 1 then the stack space required is O(log(N)).
If you had the degenerate case where the width was 1 then the tree becomes a linked list and the space requirements are O(N).
Some languages/compilers will be able to optimize away the recursion so that the space requirements are actually constant (but this is dependent on what you are doing/returning during the traversal).

Comment: I believe you have a typo. For a tree that degenerates into a list there will be O(N) function calls.

Answer (score 1):

> In mathematics, computer science, and
>   related fields, big O notation
>   describes the limiting behavior of a
>   function when the argument tends
>   towards a particular value or
>   infinity, usually in terms of simpler
>   functions. Big O notation allows its
>   users to simplify functions in order
>   to concentrate on their growth rates:
>   different functions with the same
>   growth rate may be represented using
>   the same O notation.

The rest [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).
And regarding your example you definitely have O(n).

Answer (score 0):

This is O(n), where n is the total number of nodes in the tree