# How to match two dictionary indexes regardless of order

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to compare two dictionary indexes and return a list of indexes that match regardless of order. I am also trying to do this without loading any packages/libraries.

(If this was SQL, it would be an `INNER JOIN` of two tables.)

I tried doing this: [Finding matching keys in two large dictionaries and doing it fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317410/finding-matching-keys-in-two-large-dictionaries-and-doing-it-fast)

But it this will only return the exact position where the dictionary indexes match.

I also tried this:
https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch01s09.html

"Problem: Given two dictionaries, you need to find the set of keys that are in both dictionaries."  (This is exactly what I'm trying to do).

```
#Attempt 1 (using 1st source from Stack Overflow):

dict1 = {'x': [8, 8, 1, 8, 2, 1], 'v': [0.98, 0.24, 0.91, 0.03, 0.04, 0.75]}
dict2 = {'x': [0, 8, 8, 1, 3, 3], 'v': [0.98, 0.78, 0.66, 0.08, 0.42, 0.21, 0.04]}

def common_indx(dict1,dict2):
    dict1Set = set(dict1['x'])
    dict2Set = set(dict2['x'])

    for name in dict1Set.intersection(dict2Set):
        return(name)

common_indx(dict1,dict2)

Out: 8
```

```
#Attempt 2 (Using Python Cookbook):

intersect = []
for item in some_dict.keys(  ):
    if another_dict.has_key(item):
        intersect.append(item)
print "Intersects:", intersect
```

This doesn't work because it's in python 2 but the book is answering exactly what I need to do.

My expected outcome is `[1,8]`, which are only the indexes that match in both dictionaries, regardless of position.

Comment: You are intersection *two lists*, not two dictionaries. `dict1['x']` and `dict2['x']` are expressions to produce those lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you return immediately for the first name:

```
for name in dict1Set.intersection(dict2Set):
    return(name)
```

You'd want to turn the intersection into a list instead:

```
return list(dict1Set.intersection(dict2Set))
```

or just return the set itself, without conversion to a list. You can also use the `&` operator on two sets:

```
return list(set(dict1['x']) & set(dict2['x']))
```

The Python cookbook code intersects the **keys**, while your own code intersects the **values of a single key**. That's something different.

It otherwise doesn't work because the `dictionary.has_key()` method is removed in Python 3, but you can use `key in dictionary` instead. You can also intersect the [dictionary view objects for the keys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

```
shared_keys = dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()  # The intersection of the keys
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you Martijn! However, shared_keys did not work as intended. I have noticed that whenever i call the .keys() method I just get the names of the index and values.  So for this example, I would get {'v', 'x'} Do you know what is causing this to happen?

Comment: @Jacky: yes, because those are your dictionary keys. Note that there is nothing in Python dictionaries we call 'indexes', so I wrongly assumed that that's what you meant by the term. And the Python codebook code you found *only* looks at the keys.

Comment: @Jacky: I addressed that code only because you had tried it, so I explained why it breaks on Python 3, how to fix that, and how to do that same task properly. But it isn't what you were looking for to begin with.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. The concept of a dictionary has been quite confusing to me but your explanation has cleared things up very well.