# Python: Merge Multilevel dictionaries (append without replace)

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I need to merge two dictionaries (multilevel), which are (in a very reduced form) like

```
 a = {'a' : {'b' : '1'}}
 b = {'a' : {'c' : '2'}}
```

The result should be

```
 x = {'a' : {'b: '1', 'c' : '2' }}
```

Does Python (3.9) provide a function to merge them in the required way?
Or can this be done in a failsave procedure?

The actual data has several more levels with different length.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too vague what you mean by "multilevel" since you don't provide an example. But for what you show, then the following will for every key, `key`, that is common to both dictionaries `a` and `b`, update the dictionary `a[key]` with the dictionary `b[key]`. This assumes, of course, that key values are dictionaries.

```py
from copy import deepcopy

a = {'a': {'b': '1'}}
b = {'a': {'c': '2'}, 'f': {'d': '3'}}

x = deepcopy(a)
for key in b.keys():
    if key in x:
        x[key].update(b[key])
    else:
        x[key] = b[key]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```None
{'a': {'b': '1', 'c': '2'}, 'f': {'d': '3'}}
```

It is the `dict.update` method that is key (pardon the pun) to the solution. If by *multilevel* you mean that the dictionary values are dictionaries whose values are also dictionaries, then you will need a recursive algorithm.

Comment: what if there is a key in b that doesnt exist in a?

Comment: Good point. I have updated the answer with an example.

Comment: This is a good answer, there is no need to use sets (as I did).

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {'a' : {'b' : '1'}}
b = {'a' : {'c' : '2'}}

aset = set(a)
bset = set(b)

c=dict()
#first common keys
for name in aset.intersection(bset):
    c[name]=dict(a[name], **b[name])
#keys in a but not in b
for name in aset-bset:
    c[name]=a[name]
#keys in b but not in a
for name in bset-aset:
    c[name]=b[name]
#print fully merged c
print(c)
```

```
>>> {'a': {'b': '1', 'c': '2'}}
```

I used sets to simplify finding common keys etc, you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317410/finding-matching-keys-in-two-large-dictionaries-and-doing-it-fast).

On a more complete example:

```
a = {'a' : {'b' : '1'},'e':{'l':'2'},'f':{'x':'10'}}
b = {'a' : {'c' : '2'},'e':{'i':'2'},'g':{'z':'12'}}

aset = set(a)
bset = set(b)

c=dict()
for name in aset.intersection(bset):
    c[name]=dict(a[name], **b[name])
for name in aset-bset:
    c[name]=a[name]
for name in bset-aset:
    c[name]=b[name]
print(c)
```

```
>>> {'a': {'b': '1', 'c': '2'}, 'e': {'l': '2', 'i': '2'}, 'f': {'x': '10'}, 'g': {'z': '12'}}
```

Comment: Yours is an interesting method.