# What is meant by code or algorithm complexity? How can we calculate it?

Tags: code-complexity

What is meant by code or algorithm complexity? How can we calculate it? What is the meaning  of representation of complexity? I'm so confused by this term!

Answer (score 1):

This gets asked a lot, try the following

- [Plain English explanation of Big O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)
- [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)
- [Big-O for Eight Year Olds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107165/big-o-for-eight-year-olds)

Comment: Don't forget Cyclometric Complexity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclometric_complexity