# BIg O Notation: n*logn

Tags: big-o

I am confuse about the big O notation.

O(n^2)  -> it grows quadratically,    when you **double** the size of n, the number of operations would actually be multiplied by a factor of **4**.

O(n*log(n)) -> when you double the size of n, the number of operations would actually be multiplied by a factor of how much???

```
2n*log (2n)  / n*log(n) = 2*log(2n)/log(n) =2*log_n (2n)
```

Is this the factor?

Comment: Yup, it depends on the value of `N`. For large values it's going to approach 2 (but always be larger than that).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107165/big-o-for-eight-year-olds?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly?rq=1 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The O (big-oh) notation is the boundary in the asymptotic case, it's related to the number of operations although not an exact figure.

If you double n in a `O(n log n)` processing algorithm you have.

`log (2n) = log(n) + log(2)` so you could assume you would have

`2 (log(n)+log(2) / log(n))` times the initial operation.

Or as @Jeremy said `2(1+log base n of 2)`

Comment: or 2(1+log base n of 2).